# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter. Stuck in below issue.

```
  double weight = 0;

  weightIncrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight += 1;
    });
  }

  weightDecrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight -= 1;
    });
  }
      Text(
        cardType == CardType.age ? "$age".toString() : "$weight".toString())
```

Using above on some button. And setting value to Text throws below error.
I/flutter (22691): The following assertion was thrown building Calculator(dirty, state: _CalculatorState#82a4b):
I/flutter (22691): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' of 'function result'

Comment: Based on the error you shared, it doesn't look like the error is being caused by the code that you are showing us here. As a side note, why are you putting your variables inside double quotes and then using `.toString()`? You should be able to just do one or the other.

Comment: Yes I used $ as well but was getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error statement itself is giving the answer here, Basically what it says is that the state you are trying to set is of type int and it(The dart compiler) expects it to be of type double. And it assumes that because you have defined the type of weight as a double. (`double weight = 0;`).

The quick and straightforward solution is to change the type of weight while initializing it as: `int weight = 0;`

I get your point about why you might be initializing the weight as a double because the weight doesn't have to be a whole number. To follow that, you might want to set the state with a double as follows:

First initialize the weight as `double weight = 0.0;` then modify your functions as:

```
   weightIncrement() {
      setState(() {
        weight += 1.0;
      }
   }
```

And the same for decrementing the weight.

Comment: You can add an `int` to a `double`, the output will be a `double`. This is not the issue.

Comment: I did in the same way but was not working. It worked after flutter clean seams reload was not applying changes correctly. Thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: Same exact issue. I had to restart the flutter run in order to apply changes, because if it just did hot reload, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

there's you are making mistake in datatype of variable. first if you don't want to change weight datatype then assign double value

```
double weight = 0.0;

  weightIncrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight += 1.0;
    });
  }

  weightDecrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight -= 1.0;
    });
  }
      Text(
        cardType == CardType.age ? "$age".toString() : "$weight".toString())
```

and another solution just change weight datatype double to int

```
 int weight = 0;



weightIncrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight += 1;
    });
  }



 weightDecrement() {
    setState(() {
      weight -= 1;
    });
  }
      Text(
        cardType == CardType.age ? "$age".toString() : "$weight".toString())
```